# How to handle conflicting struct definitions in a C application

Tags: c, struct, namespaces

I've got an application that reads data from a file in a proprietary binary format. The company provides header files with structures that make parsing the file straight forward. So far so good.

The vendor has just released a totally new format and provided a new set of header files. Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on your point of view), these headers contain structures with the same name but totally different definition.

So here's my problem - I have two header files that define the same structs with different definitions and my application needs to support both the old and the new version of the file format at the same time. The header file is a couple of thousand lines long so tweaking that isn't really feasible.

What's the best way of making this work in C? In C++ I could wrap each struct in a namespace, but I'm not sure how to solve this with C...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create separate library for each one and dynamically load appropriate library and call the function.

Comment: @radar unfortunately, the app needs to be support both file formats at the same time. I could create wrapper functions in separate libraries I guess, but I was hoping for something less intense :)

Comment: Shouldn't you just scream in horror and break all ties with that fine vendor? :)

Comment: Just a side note. In C++, thanks to name mangling, you cannot really do anything unless you can recompile all their sources.

Answer (score 3):

Use macros to rename the structure in one of your header files:

% cat header1.h

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

struct mystruct {
    int content;
};

#endif /* HEADER1_H */
```

% cat header2.h

```c
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

struct mystruct {
    char *somestring;
};

#endif /* HEADER2_H */
```

% cat test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header1.h"

#define mystruct mystruct_hdr2
#include "header2.h"
#undef mystruct


int main(void) {
    struct mystruct one;
    struct mystruct_hdr2 two;

    one.content = 1;
    two.somestring = "test";

    printf("%d, %s\n", one.content, two.somestring);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `#define` for the header guards should go immediately after the `#ifdef`, not at the tail of the file.  Here, it probably won't matter, but in general, it does.  It would also, probably, be sensible to have the code doing the renaming in a header of its own, rather than implementing the renaming _ad hoc_ in the files that need to include both headers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, fixed. Didn't really pay attention to what vim had generated before I started typing :)

Comment: @DanKruchinin thanks for this, it's given me hope! :D The only issue is that the header file I'm working with contains hundreds of definitions. Is there any way to apply this sort of change globally for a header file rather than one struct at a time? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with this - you could get linking problems if the name of the struct(s) also appears as part of a function name or variable name.

Comment: @PeterM: Not really; you have to know which names need mapping, and map them.  You might use a version-number suffix on both headers, so that when the vendor releases the third version, you'll already have done the renaming on the current versions.

Comment: @PeterM Not that I know of. Although, you can write a script that collects all the definitions in your header

Comment: Technically this is UB/malformed program and can break an implementation that's really bent on disallowing any form of standard incompliannce. To maje ut kosher you need to recompile their sources with the new headers.