# C++11, wrapper class for handling different versions of C struct versions

Tags: c, c++11, struct

EDIT:
I think the version is known at run-time instead of compile-time so I'm not able to add it as a compile option to the gcc cmd.  Which is why I have to support both versions based on whatever version the hardware reports back.

So I'm dealing with firmware where I am required to support multiple definitions for versions of the same C struct.  We created our own header file as defined by the interface documentation of a memory controller based on the vendor's C struct definition.

```
// For simplicity lets pretend that this is the struct for version 1
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) ver1 {
    int x;
    int y;
} ver1;
```

I also have an existing API that uses this interface already that needs to be replaced by some sort of class wrapper (I believe), or a wrapper that plays well with the existing API.

```
void function_call(ver1 v1);
```

Only one instance (ver 1 or ver 2) of the struct can exist at any time
ver 1 for a certain fw version, and ver 2 after a certain fw version

ver2 is my extended version of ver1, I am naming it as ver2 for the hope of using some sort of factory to select the right C-style struct.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) ver2 {
    int x;
    int y;
    int w; // new
    int z; // new
 } ver2;
```

Before creating a ver 2 I was looking into options such as the decorator or adaptor design pattern I could try a fancy CRTP template style I found on Hands-On Design Patterns but for simplicity, I'll illustrate with this scheme where I could possibly "add-on" to ver1:

```
struct ver2 : public ver1 {
    int w;
    int z;
}
```

But then I learned that C++ doesn't guarantee the same class layout
[C struct Inheritance vs C++ POD struct Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872961/c-struct-inheritance-vs-c-pod-struct-inheritance)
and potential alignment issues (I'm not too familiar with it) so I don't think it is a real option for me to use.

I found this example on stackoverflow but I don't like the idea of adding include headers in the struct [How to handle conflicting struct definitions in a C application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853244/how-to-handle-conflicting-struct-definitions-in-a-c-application).
There is a similar example here using a similar base class
[C++ design for multiple versions of same interface (enumerations / structures in header files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631469/c-design-for-multiple-versions-of-same-interface-enumerations-structures-in) which I don't think I can even use due to inheritance impact on the class layout.

Unless there is a valid reason to use the techniques of the links above, I was considering a wrapper class that returns the right version based on a selector. First I'll define a free function to leverage this.

```
int get_fw_version(int target);
```

I'm working on C++11 so I'm limited on auto return type deduction and below is just some draft code I'm trying to think up, not complete, doesn't compile, just illustrating my thought process.  I haven't considered composition yet since IDK how that will quite work.  Looking for ideas.

```
 int main() {
     // Roughly how I would like to use it...

    const int fw_ver = get_fw_version(target);
    auto ver_inst = ver_factory(fw_ver);

    
    function_call( ver_inst.get_data() );

 return 0;
 }
```

I am not sure if I can do this without polymorphism where the base class gets ver1 and but the derived class has ver2.

Rough idea where I am at, I tried doing CRTP but I hit the problem that the base class needs to be a template and I can't use a heterogeneous base type (e.g. shared_ptr). Trying the non-CRTP way IDK how to set up the abstract base class with the get_data() method. Without the compiler complains saying that the base doesn't have a get_data method, which, makes sense

```
// I can't figure out how to add T get_data() here without adding a template param. This base function is really to delegate common member methods and trying to keep a common base for polymorphism.
class base {
    virtual ~base() = 0;
    // ?? get_data() = 0 or some other method
};

class ver1_derived : public base
{
    ver1 data;

    public:
    ver1_derived() = default;
    ver1 get_data() {
        return data;
    }
};

class ver2_derived : public base
{
    ver2 data;

    public:
    ver2_derived() = default;
    ver2 get_data() {
        return data;
    }
};

// should be using unique_ptr but I can't at work....
shared_ptr<base> ver_factory(const int fw_ver) {
    if(fw_ver <= 1) 
        return make_shared<ver1_derived>();

    return make_shared<ver2_derived>();
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put the different versions in header files in different directories (`v1/the_struct.h` or `v2/the_struct.h`) and let the build system select which one by supplying `-I<version>`? There would be no inheritance at all and in your code you'd simply `#include "the_struct.h"`.

Comment: I think the version is known at run-time instead of compile-time so I'm not able to add it as a compile option.  Which is why I have to support both versions based on whatever version the hardware reports back.

Comment: Ah... I see. Bummer ...

Comment: Many options: (1) convert ver1 to ver2 (2) convert ver2 to ver1 (3) wrap both in C++ classes that inherit from common base (4) `template <class Ver> void function_call(Ver& ver)`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. how does (1) or (2) look like? I can't use inheritance since it'll change the class layout? I'm interested in (3).

Comment: "Convert" means you create a new object based on the value of the old object. If ver2 adds new fields that are not relevant to you, copy common fields from ver2 to ver1 omitting the new fields. If the new fields are important but you can have fill them with some sensible defaults, copy ver1 fields to ver2 and set missing fields to the default value.

Comment: (3) would look like an abstract class Base with no data members that provides an interface to the common part of ver1 and ver2. Then one class which holds ver1 as a member inherits and implements Base, and another class doers the same with ver2.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.I updated my question to reflect the issue I'm having trying to get a non-template base class.  options 1 and 2 are not possible for me because ver1 and ver2 are C structs I have to interface with and there are HW checks for the size of the struct on the vendor side so I can't use c++ "conversion" (I think) since it changes the class layout. So I'm actually doing all this to send the "right" struct...I think I'm just one hint away..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on an inheritance schemed and ended up taking two different code paths based on the template type.

So

```
   if(fw_ver <= 1) 
        function_call<ver1>();
   } else {
       function_call<ver2>();
   }
```